# Windows: Cant access self hosted URL by IP

Tags: windows, networking

I am not sure how I managed this, but I can no longer access self-hosted web servers using the IP of my machine, only localhost. I am also unable to access them from another machine on my network.

I have tried resetting my network settings, but that didn't fix it.

The only thing I can think of that might have caused this is when I tried https://dragonfruit.network/onionfruit

The program never worked for me and I uninstalled it. Ever since, I am having the issues described above.

I am also unable to access my routers (apple airport) through the air port utility program.

Doing a network scan adds my ISP to the end of my machine's name where it didn't before. Chris-PC.cable.virginm.net

Hopefully something in there will give you suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was Avast firewall. It decided to set my network as an untrusted one. It's been installed that long that I forgot I even had it. Installing that TOR utility must have triggered it to switch my trusted network to an untrusted one.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.